# How to get total number of leaves of an employee in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am having some set of records returned from my SQL query where I get employee name and his start and end date of leave of the current month. My problem is I get two records of same employee but with different leave dates. Now I want all the dates of that employee (which should combine his both the leave data) when he is on leave.

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT distinct emp.emp_name, 
       NULL as start_date,
       NULL as end_date 
FROM employee_details emp 
WHERE emp.group_name = 'A' and 
      Emp_Id not in (SELECT distinct emp.Emp_Id 
                     FROM employee_details emp, offshore_leave_calendar olc 
                     WHERE emp.emp_id = olc.emp_id AND 
                           emp.group_name = 'A' and 
                           datepart(mm,olc.start_date) = datepart(mm, getdate()))
union 

SELECT distinct emp.emp_name,
       olc.Start_Date,
       olc.End_Date 
FROM employee_details emp, offshore_leave_calendar olc     
WHERE emp.emp_id = olc.emp_id AND 
      emp.group_name = 'A' and 
      datepart(mm, olc.start_date) = datepart(mm,getdate())
```

My output of the above query is:

```
Emp_Name            start_date               end_date
John         
Sophia       
Olivia
Davis          3/20/2017 12:00:00 AM    3/24/2017 12:00:00 AM
Clark          3/21/2017 12:00:00 AM    3/24/2017 12:00:00 AM
Paul         
Thomas         3/21/2016 12:00:00 AM    3/29/2016 12:00:00 AM
Thomas         3/6/2017 12:00:00 AM     3/10/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

In the above output **Thomas** is on twice on leave in current month. So I want all the dates of Thomas whenever he is on leave in a list in C#. The output dates should be:

```
3/06/2016
3/07/2016
3/08/2016
3/09/2016
3/10/2016
3/21/2016
3/22/2016
3/23/2016
3/24/2016
3/25/2016
3/26/2016
3/27/2016
3/28/2016
3/29/2016
```

Can anyone help me on this?

I am having a list as:

```
 List<LeaveData> leaveList = new List<LeaveData>();
```

where LeaveData class has these three definitions:

```
public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
public DateTime? start_date { get; set; }
public DateTime? end_date { get; set; }
```

Against each date of the month I want to assign an employee and the employee who is on leave should not be assigned. SO I looped all the dates of the month and wrote this code for finding dates on which employee is on leave:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dates.Length; i++)
{
    for (DateTime? date = leaveList[index].start_date; date <= leaveList[index].end_date; date = date.Value.AddDays(1))
            {
                allDates.Add(date);
            }
}
```

where index is the count from 0-7 (in this case). Index will be pointing to any of the employee that I got from my SQL query.

Comment: Please share your C# code as well.

Comment: group the records in your dataset by the employee name

Comment: How are you doing this? Entity Framework or something?

Comment: @KobyDouek I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of you employees in C#

```
List<Employee> employees = ... 

IEnumerable<DateTime> leaveDates = 
    employees.Where(emp=>emp.Emp_Name == "Thomas")
             .SelectMany(emp =>
                Enumerable.Range(0, emp.EndDate.Subtract(emp.StartDate).Days + 1)
                          .Select(d => e.StartDate.AddDays(d)));
```

**Explanation**

This will get range of dates between two dates:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, e.EndDate.Subtract(e.StartDate).Days + 1)
                          .Select(d => e.StartDate.AddDays(d)));
```

The rest is just simple linq for `Where` and `SelectMany` is to project and flatten the results into the same sequence

**Edit**
As your comments: if you have your data in `leaveList[index]` then you would just replace "Thomas" with `leaveList[index].Emp_Name`. And also i've added check for null dates:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> leaveDates = 
        employees.Where(emp=>emp.Emp_Name == leaveList[index].Emp_Name && 
                             emp.StartDate.HasValue && emp.EndDate.HasValue)
                 .SelectMany(emp =>
                     Enumerable.Range(0,
                                emp.EndDate.Value.Subtract(emp.StartDate.Value).Days + 1)
                              .Select(d => e.StartDate.Value.AddDays(d)));
```

Comment: at **e.Emp_Name** it is giving error that **Cannot convert type string to bool**.

Comment: Missed the seconde `=`. Check it now.

Comment: It's giving error now on e: 
Error A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Comment: Obviously, You have another variable called e in your current scope. i've change to emp... feel free to change to whatever you'd like

Comment: I have changed ur code according to mine: IEnumerable<DateTime> leaveDates = leaveList.Where(item2 => item2.Emp_Name == leaveList[index].Emp_Name).SelectMany(item2 => Enumerable.Range(0, item2.leaveList[index].end_date.Subtract(item2.leaveList[index].start_date).Days + 1).Select(d => tem2.leaveList[index].start_date.AddDays(d))); but this also giving error: 
CS1061 'LeaveData' does not contain a definition for 'leaveList' and no extension method 'leaveList' accepting a first argument of type 'LeaveData' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I don't understand what is `index` and why do you do that? the whole point was that you wanted to group together few records.

Comment: index is the count of employees in leavelist

Comment: Can you please explain me this error: **'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for Subtract and no extension method accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found** Since my DateTime has **?** as it contains nullable values as well.

Comment: Is there any way where I can display all the dates in leaveDates in a Label separated by comma (,).

Answer (score 0):

A class with following property

```
public class EmployeeLeave
{
   public string empName {get; set;}
   public List<DateTime> LeavesDate {get;set;}
}
```

Iterate over all employee

```
var allEmployeeLeaveList = new List<EmployeeLeave>();

  foreach(var employee in LeaveData)
  {
    var tempDate = employee.StartDate.valueOrDefault();
    while((employee.EndDate.valueOrDefault() - tempDate).TotalDays > 0)
        {
         if( allEmployeeLeaveList .Any(x=>x.empName == employee.Emp_Name ))
           {
              allEmployeeLeaveList .Where(x=>x.empName == employee.Emp_Name    ).LeavesDate .Add(tempDate);
           }
       else
           {
        allEmployeeLeaveList.Add(new EmployeeLeave
                                     {
                                      empName  = employee.Emp_Name ,
                                      LeavesDate = new List<DateTime>  
                                                     {tempDate}         
                                      });
           }

        tempDate.AddDays(1)
        }
  }
```

Comment: this EmployeeList will be the list that contains my emp name, StartDate,EndDate?

Comment: Also what is the **listDateTime** in the line someList.listDateTime.Add(tempDate);

Comment: but here I want the list to iterate only for that employee where the **leaveList[index]** is pointing

Comment: For Example here the **leaveList[index]** is pointing to Thomas so it should iterate only Thomas's Leaves, i.e, from 6-10 and then 21-29.

Comment: Look at the answer, it will return you the same result you are expecting, But anyways above snippet will bind all the leave dates for all employee.. further you can filter any particular employee as per your need

Comment: okk but what is LeavesDate  in public List<DateTime> LeavesDate {get;set;}

Comment: So should I add that list in my already built up class LeaveData?

Comment: `LeaveData` will contain two instance of "Thomas", I would prefer a new class.

Answer (score 0):

see requirement that you want to assign leave date to "Present Employee" seem easy to me,and it can be done in sql itself,provided we have complete info in the first place.

and what is the criteria of assigning employee.
I have worked on your output assuming it to be another CTE.

```
declare @t table(Emp_Name varchar(50),start_date datetime,end_date datetime)
insert into @t VALUES
('John',null,null)
,('Sophia',null,null)
,('Olivia',null,null)
,('Davis','3/20/2017 12:00:00 AM ',   '3/24/2017 12:00:00 AM')
,('Clark','3/21/2017 12:00:00 AM','3/24/2017 12:00:00 AM')
,('Paul',null,null)
,('Thomas','3/21/2016 12:00:00 AM',    '3/29/2016 12:00:00 AM')
,('Thomas','3/6/2017 12:00:00 AM',     '3/10/2017 12:00:00 AM')
;With CTE as
(
select  *,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by Emp_Name order by start_date)RN 
,DATEDIFF(day,start_date,end_date) rn1
from @t
where start_date is not null

)
,CTE1 AS(

select Emp_Name,start_date , end_date,rn,rn1 from cte

UNION ALL
SELECT c.Emp_Name,DATEADD(day,1,c1.start_date), c.end_date,c1.rn
,c1.rn1
FROM cte c
inner join cte1 c1 on c.Emp_Name=c1.Emp_Name
where c.rn=c1.rn
and  C1.start_date<c.end_date
)

SELECT Emp_Name
,start_date leavedates 
FROM CTE1
order by Emp_Name
```